# How to Update UITableView with data passed from another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to populate a `UITableView` with data passed to the `ViewController` from `LoginViewController` after the user logs in.

The current process is:

`ViewController` loads first, if user is not logged in `LoginViewController` pops up over the top.  User logs in, details are fetched from the database (`userDetails` and `communities`).  `LoginViewController` is then dismissed and `ViewController` is again visible.

The `communities` variable is being populated and values transferred from `LoginViewController` to `ViewController`.

I believe my problem is `func tableView` is run before the data is fetched from the user logging in.

`print ("test 1: ",communities)` just prints [],[],[],[]

However `print ("test 2: ",communities)` prints the correct values.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UsernameSentDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var receiveUsername: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailText: UILabel!
var userEmail: String?
var communities = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var communitiesTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func unwindToHome(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {


}


//recieves email address from delegate from LoginViewController
func userLoggedIn(data: String) {

  userEmailText.text = data
     }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.communitiesTableView.delegate = self
    self.communitiesTableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print ("test 1: ",communities) //not printing value 
    return self.communities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let title = self.communities[indexPath.row]

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = title

    return cell

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "loginView" {
        let loginViewController: LoginViewController = segue.destination as! LoginViewController
        loginViewController.delegate = self
    }

    if segue.identifier == "createCommunitySegue" {
        let createCommunityController: CreateNewCommunity = segue.destination as! CreateNewCommunity
        createCommunityController.myEmail = userEmailText.text
    }


}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    print ("test 2: ",communities) //prints values correctly
   let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.bool(UserDefaults.standard)(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");

    if(!isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);
    }

}


@IBAction func logoutButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    UserDefaults.set(UserDefaults.standard)(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);

}


@IBAction func createCommunityTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {


}


}
```

This is the code for CreateCommunityViewController:

```
import UIKit

class CreateNewCommunity: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var communityNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

var myEmail: String?


@IBAction func cancelButtonPapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindCommunity", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func createCommunityButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let communityName = communityNameTextField.text;
    if (communityName!.isEmpty){
        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "You must name your Community");

        return;
    }else{

        func generateRandomStringWithLength(length: Int) -> String {

            var randomString = ""
            let letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

            for _ in 1...length {
                let randomIndex  = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(letters.characters.count)))
                let a = letters.index(letters.startIndex, offsetBy: randomIndex)
                randomString +=  String(letters[a])
            }

            return randomString
        }

        let communityCode = generateRandomStringWithLength(length: 6)
        passwordTextField.text = communityCode

        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/createCommunity.php?");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";

        let postString = "communityname=\(communityName!)&code=\(communityCode)&email=\(myEmail!)";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {

        if (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]) != nil {

            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Community Registered", message: "Community Code:\(communityCode)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);


            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){(action) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        }
        }
        task.resume()


    }

}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put communitiesTableView.reloadData() in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Excellent! This solution worked! One addition though - if I create another community whilst logged in- (via another view controller) I need it to update also.  How do I call 'communitiesTableView.reloadData()' from inside another function in another View Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call reload data in didSet. E.g. `var communities = [] { didSet { yourtableview.realoadData()
 }
}`

Comment: no unfortunately that didn't work. Though maybe that is because that command isn't getting run again until ViewController reloads? which it doesn't do upon a new community being created.

Comment: This command should be called when communities change. Make sure you are affecting comutties correctly. If you share the bit of code where you are doing prepareForSegue it might be helpful to see how you are passing community

Comment: i've updated the question with more details  - the CreateCommunity script

Comment: in okaction closure, get a handle on the viewcontroller instance i think this should be your parent view controller,  and append the newly created community to the existing list of communities. Keep the didSet command. Hope this helps

Comment: sorry @ReginaldoCosta I don't understand how to: "get a handle on the view controller instance and append the newly created community to the existing list of communities"